# Usage of adjuncts this week / month / year

Tags: phrase-usage, adverbial-phrases, adjuncts

1. I am your math teacher this week / month / year.
2. I will be your math teacher this week / month / year.
3. I have been your math teacher this week / month / year.

While the first sentence can be uttered at any time of this week / month / year,  what about the second and third?

I feel that the second can be only said **at the first day or first class** of this week / month / year.  The 3rd sentence can be said after the middle of this week / month / year.

Comment: The second works until teaching has started. The third starts working near the end of the time period.

Comment: @gotube  Thank you. It seems words after "be" have a influence on the acceptability.  Do you think " I have been **busy** this year"  works in, for example, March？